# Change line spacing with setspace without changing space before chapter headings

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, koma-script, line-spacing, setspace

I want to use `onehalfspacing` throughout my document except for the bibliography, the TOC and the list of figures and what so not. I could put all of these in groups and change the spacing within them, but doing so changes the space above their chapter headings. It looks bad when all the chapter headings are a certain distance from the top of the page except for the aforementioned parts of the document.

Is there any way to make `setspace` not change the spacing of the headings or is there any equivalent to `\AfterTOCHead` for the LOF, bibliography and so on?

MWE:

`document.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\autocite{small}
\begingroup
\singlespacing
\printbibliography
\endgroup
\chapter*{appendix}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

`mybib.bib`:

```
@article{small,
author = {Freely, I.P.},
title = {A small paper},
journal = {The journal of small papers},
year = 1997,
volume = {-1},
note = {to appear},
}
```

In this MWE, the TOC heading and the chapter heading are all on the same position and the bibliography heading is higher towards the top of the page.

Comment: please add a small bib file to the question, not use an external link

Comment: Okay, I added a bib file to the MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

biblatex has a similar hook `\AtBeginBibliography`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\AfterTOCHead{\singlespacing}
\AtBeginBibliography{\singlespacing}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\autocite{doody}
\printbibliography

\chapter*{appendix}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Are there similar hooks for \listoffigures and \listoftables or is there a way to prevent \setspace from changing the vertical space before chapter headings?

Comment: doesn't \AfterTOChead apply to the lists anyway? If not check the documentation, I'm sure that koma/tocbasic has a similar hook for the lists too.

Comment: Thanks, will do!